# ListView: accessing siblings from a list item

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view with a seekBar per item in the list.

When the user modifies one of the seekbars, I want the rest of the seekbars modified also.

I need to access its sibling items, find the seekbar view, and change its value.

To do this, I was keeping all the item views in an array in the Adapter, but when I try to update these view, inconsistent things happen (the views doesn't always get updated in an unpredictable way).

I guess I am missing something with the way listView manages the items an the way it calls getView() method on the adapter.

What would be the proper way to access the sibling view of a list item view?

Comment: how about getting the onItemClickListener and in that asking that if seekBarValue is changed then set that changed value for all of the items and reAttach the adapter  with saying dataChange notified?

Comment: you post your itemclickListener code  and then I can give you the solution in the code!

Comment: Thank you! The fact is that I want to be able to slide the seekBar and gracefully slide all the other seekBars at the same time, without the user needing to raise the finger... If I call "notifyDataSetChanged" the view is redrawn and the seekBar doesn't keep sliding with the finger...